# Need assistance with Prestashop label code

Tags: prestashop

I want to add a Best Seller label to products in Prestashop 1.6, on both product list and product pages, the same as the labels for New Products. Can anybody point me in the right direction to accomplishing this, if it is possible, i.e will it require a controller etc.

At this stage all I have tried is simply,

```
{if isset($best_sellers) && $best_sellers|@count > 0}
<span class="bestseller">
<label>{l s='best seller' mod='modulename'}</label>
</span>
{/if}
```

This did not work. I don't need any help with the css, I can handle that. Thanks

Hello again,

Using some of the information you gave me below I have come up with the following to add a best seller label to my custom module without using an override.

Following is the function:

```
public function getcustomBestSellersLabel($params) 
        {   
        $id_product = (int)$params['product']['id_product'];

        return Db::getInstance()->executeS('SELECT `id_product`, `sale_nbr` AS customnbr FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'product_sale ps WHERE `id_product` = '.(int)$id_product.' ORDER BY `customnbr` DESC LIMIT 5');
        }
```

and in my hook

```
public function hookdisplayCustomBestSellersTag($params)
        {   
            $id_product = (int)Tools::getValue('id_product');

            if (!$this->isCached('custombestsellertag.tpl', $this->getCacheId($id_product))) {

            $custombestsellers = CustomModule::getCustomBestSellersLabel($params);

            $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
            'custombestsellers' => Module::getInstanceByName('CustomModule')->getCustomBestSellersLabel($params),
            'id_product' => $id_product,
            ));
            }       

        return $this->display(__FILE__, 'views/templates/front/custombestsellerlabel.tpl', $this->getCacheId());

        }
```

and in my tpl

```
{if (isset($custombestsellers) && $custombestsellers)}

        <span class="custom-best-seller-label">

        <label>{l s='best seller' mod='CustomModule'}</label>

        </span>

        {/if}
```

This actually works except for one problem, the LIMIT doesn't work. I have tested it in phpMyAdmin where it does work. I have tested it with LIMIT 5 and there is no change, instead all products in the product_sale database table are showing a label.

Can you give me some advice on how to fix this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's much more complicated than that, to achieve that you need:

1. create override of `Product.php` method called `getProductProperties`
2. check if product is in TOP X in terms of sales in `PREFIX_product_sale` table
3. if so, mark it as a bestseller by adding a new variable (alternative is to do this directly in SQL statement)

if you'll do everything properly and new variable will be available you would have a chance to use it like this:

`{if $product.is_bestseller}bestseller label{/if}`

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply. I thought it was going to be quite involved. I would prefer not to use an override, plus I should have mentioned this is for a custom module with it's own hook.

Comment: it would be hardo to achieve this without override in 1.6 as there are no perfect hooks to do that (modify product list and add new variable), there are some hooks like hookActionProductListModifier but this hook is not working well with `blocklayered`